# About knots and 4-valent planner graph

Tags: knot-theory

I have some difficulty in reading a proof about Jones polynomial of n alternating link.It states a Lemma:

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dftgO.png)

---

I stick into the proof about 4-valent planner graph.Actually I have tried to draw some diagram to help myself to get the idea.For example:

---

This is a knot diagram D[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY5tK.png)

---

with the states s+D and s-D:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCMhQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XuVM.png)also the graph:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGYMD.png)

---

The proof said that by Euler number of the sphere,it shows that the regions is n+2(edges is 2n).So that is my question?Is there any problem in my diagram such that I cannot get the result the proof talking about?
thank you

---

Edit:For an other example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWYMK.png)

Comment: A knot diagram is a 4-valent planar graph where the vertices are labeled with crossing information.  The edges of the graph correspond to arcs of the knot.  I do not understand the significance of the red graph you drew.  The point is that $4n=2e$, so $n-e+f=2$ implies $f=2+n$, but on the other hand $f=\lvert s_+D\rvert+\lvert s_-D\rvert$ for an alternating diagram.

Comment: Thank you very much.Your idea is that the diagram I updated?I hope I have get your meaning

Comment: Yes, with your new image of the diagram for a trefoil, you have 3 vertices, 6 edges, and 5 regions.